# Invalid Code Signing Entitlements while uploading build to Testflight

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

While I am trying to upload my build to Testflight , I'm getting this error -

> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value '' for key 'com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment' in 'Payload/Video Audio Converter & Editor.app/Video Audio Converter & Editor' is not supported. This value should be a string value of 'Production' (ID: *********-#####-******-######-*************)

Comment: Have you checked your entitlements and removed the invalid value?

Comment: I have no idea about this. Can you guide me on where to find this value? @Paulw11

Comment: Check the entitlements file in your Xcode project